# Как настроить Nginx для работы с History Api в SPA пиложении?

Tags: nginx, api, history, spa

Только начал работать с Nginx (ранее использовал Apache) и столкнулся с проблемой настройки конфигурации проекта.
Есть 2 основных файла в публичной папке:

- index.html - SPA приложение с History Api
- api.php - API приложения.

На Apache роутинг имел такой вид:

**SPA (index.html)**

- example.com/user
- example.com/user/1
- example.com/user/1/edit
- example.com/user/1/delete

**API (api.php)**

- example.com/api.php/user.list
- example.com/api.php/user.view
- example.com/api.php/user.edit
- xample.com/api.php/user.delete

Как в Nginx настроить такую работу роутинга, что бы при наличии префикса /api/ данные уходили в api.php? а остальные в index.html?

Привожу примеры того как должно работать:

- example.com/param_1/param_2/param_n ==> **index.html**
- example.com **/api/** param_1/param_2/param_n.method ==> **api.php**

**UPD #1:**

```
server {
    listen 8.8.8.8:80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /home/example/data/logs/example.access.log;
    error_log /home/example/data/logs/example.error.log;

    root /home/example/data/www/example.com/www;
    index index.html;
    rewrite ^/api$ /api.php last;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
        }

        if ($request_filename !~ "\.(js|htc|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$") {
            rewrite ^(.*) /index.html last;
        }
    }

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$args;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        set  $script     $uri;
        set  $path_info  "";
        if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.+)") {
            set  $script     $1;
            set  $path_info  $2;
        }

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
}
```

**UPD #2:** - Структура публичной папки

- www/

  - css/
  - fonts/
  - js/
  - img/
  - template/
  - temp/
  - uploads/
  - **api.php**
  - **index.html**

Comment: а интепретацию php вы уже настроили?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что у вас ещё есть картинки, стили и скрипты...

Comment: "Нагуглил" до такого вида (UPD #1), все работает как как нужно. Можете проверить на адекватность и правильность данной конфиги?